# HTTParty::Response is cast into Hash when passed as argument to another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have a service method that makes api requests and if the response was not ok, it would notify Bugsnag. It looks like this:

```
def send_request
  @response = HTTParty.get(api_endpoint, options)
  return JSON.parse(@response.body, symbolize_names: true) if @response.ok?
  raise StandardError.new(JSON.parse(@response.body))
rescue StandardError => exception
  BugsnagService.notify(exception, @response)
end
```

My `BugsnagService#notify` looks something like this:

```
class BugsnagService
  def self.notify(exception, response = nil, **options)
    if response
      response_body = if valid_json?(response.body) # Error right here
                        JSON.parse(response.body)
                      else
                        response.body
                      end
      options[:response_body] = response_body
      options[:response_code] = response.code
    end

    # Raising exception in test and development environment, or else the exception will be
    # silently ignored.
    raise exception if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?

    Bugsnag.notify(exception) do |report|
      report.add_tab(:debug_info, options) if options.present?
    end
  end

  def self.valid_json?(json_string)
    JSON.parse(json_string)
    true
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
    false
  end
end
```

I set `response = nil` in my `notify` method because not every error is an API error, so sometimes I would just call `BugsnagService.notify(exception)`.

I found out that if I just call it like I am in the snippet above, it would raise an error saying it can't call `.body` on a `Hash`. Somehow, when I pass `@response` into `BugsnagService#notify`, the object turns from `HTTParty::Response` into `Hash`.

But if I pass something in for the `**options` parameter, it will work. So I can call it like this:

```
BugsnagService.notify(exception, @response, { })
```

I've been trying to figure this one out but I couldn't find anything that would explain this. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the way I define my parameters or if this is some bug with the `HTTParty` gem. Can anyone see why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `@response` is being passed in as the `options`, as `response` can be `nil`. The double splat is converting it to a hash.

Try:

```
def testing(x, y = nil, **z)
  puts "x = #{x}"
  puts "y = #{y}"
  puts "z = #{z}"
end

testing 1, 2, z: 3
#=> x = 1
#=> y = 2
#=> z = {:z=>3}

testing 1, y: 2
#=> x = 1
#=> y = 
#=> z = {:y=>2}

testing 1, { y: 2 }, {}
#=> x = 1
#=> {:y=>2}
#=> {}
```

I'd suggest the best approach would be to have `response` be a keyword arg, as in:

```
def self.notify(exception, response: nil, **options)
  ...
end
```

That way, you can still omit or include the response as desired, and pass in subsequent options.

Comment: Ah thank you! I totally did not think about that. It makes sense now!